# Can i see big number with Array.prototype.reduce

Tags: javascript

```
const squareList = arr => {

    return arr
        .filter(number => number > 0 && number % parseInt(number) === 0)
        .map(number => Math.pow(number, 2)) // [25,9]
        .reduce((bigN, number) => bigN > number)
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]);
console.log(squaredIntegers); // true
```

My purpose is to print the big number in the array to the console after `reduce`, but I couldn't find how to see the numbers in the  string and how to compare them.

Can I do this with `reduce`?

Comment: Your reduce function is returning a value that is incompatible with its first argument.  Perhaps you meant to return `bigN > number ? bigN : number`

Comment: Use `Number.isInteger(number)` instead of some weird `number % parseInt(number) === 0`

Answer (score 0):

most likely you want your reduce function to look like this:

```
 reduce((bigN, number) => bigN > number ? bigN : number)
```

but you can also use Math.max function:

```
const squareList = arr => {
    return Math.max(...arr
        .filter(number => number > 0 && number % parseInt(number) === 0)
        .map(number => Math.pow(number, 2)))
};
```